# Custom font in navigation drawer does not work

Tags: android, fonts, navigation-drawer

I created a custom class for my drawer. It work well except one point.

The custom font is not working.

When i custom the font in "onCreate()" it works fine. When the drawer is opening, ActionBar Title change. I set a custom font like below (same code as in onCreate) and it does not work.

In ActionBarActivity it is called like that:

```
Drawer drawer = new Drawer(this);
drawer.setUpDrawer();
```

There is my Drawer.class.

```
public class Drawer {

    /** Drawer attr **/
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private int positionDrawer;
    private Activity a;

    public Drawer(Activity a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    /**
     * Set Up the drawer with the array list of items, add animation listener etc...
     */
    public void setUpDrawer() {
        //Get DrawerLayout
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) a.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        //Get Listview into drawer
        mDrawerList = (ListView) a.findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new DrawerAdapter(a, new DrawerList().getDrawerList()));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener(a));

        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        ((ActionBarActivity) a).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the proper interactions
        // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                a,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                Log.d("TAG", "drawer close");
                Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(a.getAssets(), "Anothershabby_trial.ttf");
                SpannableStringBuilder SS = new SpannableStringBuilder(a.getTitle());
                SS.setSpan (new CustomTypefaceSpan(tf), 0, SS.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
                ((ActionBarActivity) a).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(" "+SS);
                a.invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                Log.d("TAG", "drawer open");
                Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(a.getAssets(), "Anothershabby_trial.ttf");
                SpannableStringBuilder SS = new SpannableStringBuilder(a.getResources().getString(R.string.drawer_open));
                SS.setSpan (new CustomTypefaceSpan(tf), 0, SS.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
                ((ActionBarActivity) a).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(" "+SS);
                a.invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }
}
```

Thks for your help

Comment: try setTitle(SS); instead of setTitle(" "+SS);

Comment: Thx you very much. After thinking, it is obvious ... Sorry for this ^^

Comment: now,  do you know how to add one space in front of SS?

Comment: Put space in new SpannableStringBuilder isn't it ? 
I think it is.

Comment: yes,  SS.insert(0,  ..